# Is it possible to install CUDA when using Ubuntu on a bootable USB?

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb, cuda

I have been using a bootable usb drive to run Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows 10 PC, which has worked great. Now I want to install CUDA to utilize my Nvidia 940MX GPU for AI, but can't work out how to do it. Is it possible to install CUDA when using Ubuntu on a bootable USB? If so how?
I have tried installing it by several different methods from the internet and none have worked.

Comment: Most USB Full install methods that I have seen on the internet do not include the ability to boot in UEFI mode.

Comment: Do you need to use UEFI rather than BIOS to run CUDA?

Comment: I have never installed CUDA, Have you seen this: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17/~/uefi-%2F-video-bios-download

Answer (score 1):

### Full Install vs Persistent install

With a Full install of Ubuntu to USB you can run any program that you can run on an internal drive.

**Comparison between Persistent and Full install USB**

**Advantages of a persistent install:**

1. You can use the persistent pendrive to install Ubuntu to another computer.
2. A persistent install takes up less space on the pendrive.
3. You can reset the pendrive by overwriting the old casper-rw file with a new one.
4. The install to pendrive takes less time.

**Advantages of a Full install:**

1. You can update and upgrade.
2. If you have problems or wish to modify, the solution is the same as with an internal install, (You can ask for help in these forums).
3. No ugly startup / install screen.
4. Better security, you can use full encryption
5. You can use proprietary drivers.
6. Hibernation works.
7. A persistent install is limited to a 4GB casper-rw and a 4GB home-rw persistence file, to get more persistence requires persistence partitions. Once casper-rw is full, the drive will not boot.
8. More efficient usage of disk space. Does not require reserved space for persistence.
9. Faster boot, **no automatic disk checking** or Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu screen.
10. You can do anything, run any program, use any driver, etc, that you can do on internal drive.

Note that once booted, both methods run at about the same speed. If the computer has lots of RAM Ubuntu should run mainly in RAM and there will not be a bi difference between running off internal HDD and USB3 flash drive.

**Full Install Method**
Three methods for creating a Full install USB: [How to Create a Full Install of Ubuntu 20.04 to USB Device Step by Step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-st)

Comment: Can you change from persistent to full without losing data already saved on the USB stick in the persistent install mode?

Comment: You can easily save the data as long as that data is stored in the home directory of the Persistent install. Programs will need to be reinstalled. What tool did you use to make the USB drive? It is a little easier to Rsync from a Persistent partition than from a persistent file.